# How to convert a object arraylist into a hashmap where key and value are the objects attributes

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a object arraylist like below

```
List<Model> list= new ArrayList<Model>();
```

The Model object has two attributes where both are integers.

1. id
2. count

Now I want to convert this arraylist into a Hash Map where id is the key and count is the value:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> convertedmap=new  HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Easy. Did you try ?

Comment: for (Model model : list) {
   convertedmap.put(model.getId(), model.getCount());
}// say for ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with for loop.

```
List<Model> list= new ArrayList<Model>();
Map<Integer,Integer> convertedmap=new  HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
Model model = list.get(i);

convertedmap.put(model.getId(),model.getCount());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I totally forgot this way.Anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Iterate on the list and add a new element in the map for each iterated Model object :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> convertedmap = new  HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (Model model : list){
   convertedmap.put(model.getId(), model.getCount());
}
```

Beware : If `list` has `Model` instances with as `id` field the same value,  the last instance in the List with the same id will overwrite the previous instance(s) in the created map.

You could do a check about it.

Otherwise, you can also perform the job by using the  `Collectors.toMap()` method of Java 8 :

```
Map<Integer, Integer> convertedmap = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Model::getId, Model::getCount));
```

It has an advantage over the classic loop iteration.
If the `id` value that is used as key in the map has duplicated values in the `list`, it will rise `IllegalStateException : Duplicate key...` rather than overwriting silently the map.

Comment: thanks for mentioning about IllegalStateException : Duplicate key

Answer (score 0):

First of all complete your POJO class `Model` with proper setters/getters then
you can iterate the whole ArrayList `list` and put the values in Map `convertedmap` like :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> convertedmap=new  HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for (Model md : list) {
   convertedmap.put(md.getId(), md.getCount());
}
```